# Trim MP4 video downloaded from YouTube in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I have downloaded a YouTube videoclip (using Firefox), it's a MP4 file. I have inserted it in a Keynote slide.

Can I trim this MP4 file in Keynote? I can do that with my music from iTunes library.

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim movies/video files directly in Keynote.

1. Place video to your slide.
2. Make video on your slide selected.
3. Show the `Format` sidebar, then select the `Movie` tab in the Format side bar.
4. You can trim the video in the `Trim` section (click open the disclosure triangle of `Edit Movie` if collapsed) either by dragging the sliders or directly manipulate the timecode by clicking into the timecode numbers.

Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Glad to learn about this. +1

Answer (score 2):

Open the MP4 video file with the built-in QuickTime Player app. It contains fine grained controls to easily trim a video. The trim command can be found under Edit menu, or can be invoked using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]

Once you have trimmed the video as per your liking, insert it into the Keynote slide. You may want to create a copy of the video if you wish to keep the original one intact.